# Retirar da conta quando valor for 0

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho a seguinte query:

```
SELECT 
ROUND((( notaAmbiente  + 
    notaApresentacaoDasPizzas + 
    notaQualidadeDosProdutos + 
    notaVariedadeDeSabores +
    notaAtendimentoNaLoja +
    notaAtendimentoNoTel +
    notaAgilidadeNaEntrega + 
    notaCustoBeneficio +
    notaPromocoes +
    notaSite +
    notaSatisfacao + notaSatisfacao) / 12) / 0.5, 0) * 0.5 AS mediaNotaOpiniao
FROM tbOpiniao
```

Nessa query eu pego as notas de cada tipo de avaliação, somo e divido para obter a média. Porém no meio dessas notas pode existir o valor 0 (referente a "Não sei dizer" no preenchimento do formulário que cadastra no banco), logo não posso usar esse valor na divisão, pois afetará a avaliação de forma errada.

O que eu gostaria de fazer é retirar a coluna da conta de divisão quando o valor dela for 0, subtraindo 1 do valor 12, que é a quantidade de colunas que uso pra fazer a média.

Pensei em colocar no lugar de 12 algo do tipo (SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE coluna <> 0), mas existem outras colunas além dessas do select na tabela.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como você usou o zero para indefinido, basta somar 1 ao divisor pra cada não-zero (ou 2 pra notaSatisfação, que tem peso 2 no seu exemplo):

```
SELECT 
ROUND ( ( (
   notaAmbiente  + 
   notaApresentacaoDasPizzas + 
   notaQualidadeDosProdutos + 
   notaVariedadeDeSabores +
   notaAtendimentoNaLoja +
   notaAtendimentoNoTel +
   notaAgilidadeNaEntrega + 
   notaCustoBeneficio +
   notaPromocoes +
   notaSite +
   notaSatisfacao * 2
) / (
   IF( notaAmbiente, 1, 0 ) +
   IF( notaApresentacaoDasPizzas, 1, 0 ) +
   IF( notaQualidadeDosProdutos, 1, 0 ) +
   IF( notaVariedadeDeSabores, 1, 0 ) +
   IF( notaAtendimentoNaLoja, 1, 0 ) +
   IF( notaAtendimentoNoTel, 1, 0 ) +
   IF( notaAgilidadeNaEntrega, 1, 0 ) +
   IF( notaCustoBeneficio, 1, 0 ) +
   IF( notaPromocoes, 1, 0 ) +
   IF( notaSite, 1, 0 ) +
   IF( notaSatisfacao, 2, 0 )
) ) / 0.5, 0 ) * 0.5 AS mediaNotaOpiniao
FROM tbOpiniao
```

Explicação: O `IF( condicao, seVerdadeiro, seFalso)` testa a condição, e retorna o respectivo valor. Para cada verdadeiro, somamos o peso correspondente ao divisor.

Answer (score 1):

Como você usou o zero para indefinido, basta somar 1 ao divisor pra cada não-zero

```
IF( notaAmbiente, 1, 0 ) +
   IF( notaApresentacaoDasPizzas, 1, 0 ) +
   IF( notaQualidadeDosProdutos, 1, 0 ) +
   IF( notaVariedadeDeSabores, 1, 0 ) +
```

...